# How to show 7 days from current date in ios if today is last day of the month

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uidatepicker, nsdatecomponents

I am showing seven days of month in `datepickerview`.

But my problem is how to show seven days from current date if todays current date is last day of the month.

Example : Suppose todays month is june, june has 30 days so todays date is 30 .Then my problem is how to show next 6 days from the current date,means in datepicker i want 30th june,1july,2july,3july,4july,5july,6july.

Please suggest me how to solve that problem. I also provided the code please suggest me where i am doing wrong with my code.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
    comps.day = 7;

    NSDate *sevenDays = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
    ActionSheetDatePicker *datePicker = [[ActionSheetDatePicker alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Date" datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate selectedDate:[NSDate date] minimumDate:[NSDate date] maximumDate:sevenDays target:self action:@selector(timeWasSelected:element:) origin:sender];
```

Comment: you can upvote my tick answer. It ll helpful to other SO user to search and resolve similar kind of problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can calculate next seven days by following line of code:

```
NSDate *sevenDays = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*7];
```

Then you can use in DatePicker as of your below Code.

```
ActionSheetDatePicker *datePicker = [[ActionSheetDatePicker alloc] 
    initWithTitle:@"Select Date" datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate 
    selectedDate:[NSDate date] minimumDate:[NSDate date] 
    maximumDate:sevenDays target:self 
    action:@selector(timeWasSelected:element:) origin:sender];
```

Hope This will help you.

Please add comment if you have any query regarding the same.

Happy Coding !!!

Comment: Never use 86400 for calendar calculations. If daylight saving changes during the interval you could get unexpected behavior.

Comment: @vadian yes Its Correct.. Thank you for suggestion.  I Think He wants just display date in Picker so rather then loop just use 86400.                              Questioner , Please consider Daylight saving if you are using at any other places.

Comment: @Sandeep Please make as answer if It helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Code seems to be correct, maybe issue is with third party picker you are using? Try you code with **UIDatePicker** and see if you get results you are looking for, if so it means **ActionSheetDatePicker** has some issues....

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
comps.day = 7;

NSDate *sevenDays = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:  [NSDate date] options:0];
```

Below code in with UIDatePicker looks like this...._datePicker is iboutlet UIDatePicker

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
comps.day = 7;

NSDate *sevenDays = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
[_datePicker setMinimumDate:[NSDate date]];
[_datePicker setMaximumDate:sevenDays];
```

In UIDatePicker with above code, if user scrolls to previous date picker will automatically sets on todays date, and same for 7th July if user scroll to 10th picker will automatically sets to 7th july
[image: current date...]

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
dayComponent.day = 1;

NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *nextDate = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

NSLog(@"nextDate: %@ ...", nextDate);
```

From this you can calculate next day mean if today is 30 then the next day is 1 so you can use for loop and run it seven times than you get the next seven days

Answer (score 0):

This creates an array `nextSevenDays` containing the next 7 days including today.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *startDate = [calendar startOfDayForDate:[NSDate date]];
NSMutableArray<NSDate*> * nextSevenDays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  [nextSevenDays addObject:[calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value: i toDate: startDate options: NSCalendarMatchNextTime]];
}
NSLog(@"%@", nextSevenDays);
```

To get the date 7 days from now use

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *startDate = [calendar startOfDayForDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate *sevenDaysFromNow = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value: 7 toDate: startDate options: NSCalendarMatchNextTime];
NSLog(@"%@", sevenDaysFromNow);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i ++)
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
    comps.day =i;
    NSDate *sevenDays = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:objDate.date options:0];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yy"];

    NSString *str = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:sevenDays];
    NSLog(@"str : %@",str);
}
```

Hope this code will help's you :)